# Problem of multiply two spinners in calculation length,area and temperature

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, android-spinner

The problem i'm having is the inability for the app to perform the task i designed it to.
i run the app successfully but when i click any of the spinners the list doesn't drop down at all. None of the spinners is responding at all and i don't know the problem.
I've tried everything to sort this out but i can't.
i run the code many times i don't get an error message but still the spinners don't work.
please can anyone help out?
This app is suppose to convert length, area and temperature.

String.xml file

```
<resources>
    <string name="spinner_1">From</string>
    <string name="spinner_2">To</string>
    <string-array name="conversion_type">
        <item>Length</item>
        <item>Area</item>
        <item>Temperature</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="area">
        <item>Square kilometre</item>
        <item>Square metre</item>
        <item>Square yard</item>
        <item>Square foot</item>
        <item>Square inch</item>
        <item>Square mile</item>
        <item>Hectare</item>
        <item>Acre</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="length">
        <item>Kilometre</item>
        <item>Metre</item>
        <item>Centimetre</item>
        <item>Millimetre</item>
        <item>Micrometer</item>
        <item>Mile</item>
        <item>Yard</item>
        <item>Foot</item>
        <item>Inch</item>
        <item>Nautical Mile</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="temperature">
        <item>Celsius</item>
        <item>Kelvin</item>
        <item>Fahrenheit</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Conversion Type"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#607D8B"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/text"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/first_linear"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="#cbcbcb"/>
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/conversion_type"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/text_some"
            android:background="#cbcbcb"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/first_linear"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/second_linear"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/text_from"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:text="From"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#607D8B"
                android:layout_below="@id/first_linear"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/from_spinner"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText
                android:hint="edit_text_from"
                android:id="@+id/from_edit"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Clear"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/clear_text_unit"
                android:onClick="clear_unit"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/third_text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/second_linear"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="#FFCBCBCB"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/third_text"
        android:id="@+id/fourth_linear"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/text_to"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:text="To"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#607D8B" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/to_spinner"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
            android:background="#e6e5e5"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/to_text"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fourth_linear"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#FFCBCBCB"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java file

```
package com.example.learnspinner;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int spinner_cycle_pos = 0, spinner_duration_pos = 0;


    Spinner from_spinner, to_spinner, conversion_type, duration_spinner, cycle_spinner;
    String from_spinner_string, to_spinner_string, choice_spinner;
    int from_spinner_position, to_spinner_position, choice_spinner_pos;
    Button btnConvert;
    TextView result;
    EditText quantity;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_length, adapter_temperature, adapter_area;

    BigDecimal[][] array = {{new BigDecimal("1"), new BigDecimal("1000000.0"), new BigDecimal("1195990.05"), new BigDecimal("10763910.4"), new BigDecimal("1550000000"), new BigDecimal("0.386102"), new BigDecimal("100"), new BigDecimal("247.105")},
            {new BigDecimal("1"), new BigDecimal("0.125"), new BigDecimal("0.000122073125"), new BigDecimal("0.00000011920992"), new BigDecimal("0.0000000001164153"), new BigDecimal("0.0000000000001136868377"), new BigDecimal("0.000000000000001110223024")},
            {new BigDecimal("1"), new BigDecimal("0.001"), new BigDecimal("0.000239006"), new BigDecimal("0.00000027778"), new BigDecimal("0.737562")},
            {new BigDecimal("1"), new BigDecimal("0.001"), new BigDecimal("0.000001"), new BigDecimal("0.000000001")},
            {new BigDecimal("1"), new BigDecimal("1000"), new BigDecimal("1000000"), new BigDecimal("1000000000"), new BigDecimal("1000000000000"), new BigDecimal("157.473"), new BigDecimal("2204.62"), new BigDecimal("35274")},
            {new BigDecimal("1"), new BigDecimal("1000"), new BigDecimal("100000"), new BigDecimal("10000000000"), new BigDecimal("10000000000000"), new BigDecimal("0.621371"), new BigDecimal("1093.61"), new BigDecimal("3280.84"), new BigDecimal("39370.1"), new BigDecimal("0.539953")},
            {new BigDecimal("1"), new BigDecimal("1.1111111300619"), new BigDecimal("0.0174533"), new BigDecimal("17.453300")},
            {new BigDecimal("1"), new BigDecimal("1.01325"), new BigDecimal("101325"), new BigDecimal("760")},
            {new BigDecimal("1"), new BigDecimal("1.46667"), new BigDecimal("0.44704"), new BigDecimal("1.60934"), new BigDecimal("0.868976")},
            {},  // keep blank for temperature
            {new BigDecimal("1"), new BigDecimal("0.001"), new BigDecimal("0.000016667"), new BigDecimal("0.00000027778"), new BigDecimal("0.000000011574"), new BigDecimal("0.0000000016534"), new BigDecimal("0.00000000038052"), new BigDecimal("0.00000000003171"), new BigDecimal("0.000000000003171"), new BigDecimal("0.0000000000003171")},
            {new BigDecimal("1"), new BigDecimal("1000"), new BigDecimal("0.219969"), new BigDecimal("0.879877"), new BigDecimal("3.51951"), new BigDecimal("0.0353147"), new BigDecimal("61.0237"), new BigDecimal("61023.7")}};
    String val = "0";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    private void initialise_adapters() {
        adapter_temperature = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplication(), R.array.temperature, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter_length = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplication(), R.array.length, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter_area = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplication(), R.array.area, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    }

    private void unit_converter() {
        from_spinner = findViewById(R.id.from_spinner);
        to_spinner = findViewById(R.id.to_spinner);
        result = findViewById(R.id.to_text);
        quantity = findViewById(R.id.from_edit);
        conversion_type = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.conversion_type);
        // Initialise the main spinner
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplication(), R.array.conversion_type, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        conversion_type.setAdapter(adapter);
        conversion_type.setOnItemSelectedListener(new spinner());

        from_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.from_spinner);
        to_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.to_spinner);

        initialise_adapters();

        //initally set default to  area adapter
        adapter_area.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        from_spinner.setAdapter(adapter_area);
        to_spinner.setAdapter(adapter_area);
        from_spinner_string = "Square kilometer";
        to_spinner_string = "Square kilometer";
        choice_spinner = "Area";

        //Default values
        from_spinner_position = 0;
        to_spinner_position = 0;
        choice_spinner_pos = 0;
        int spinner_cycle_pos = 0, spinner_duration_pos = 0;


        from_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new spinner());
        to_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new spinner());


        quantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                val = s.toString();
                int flag = 0;
                if (val.equals("")) {
                    flag = 1;
                    val = "0";
                }
                if (val.equals("-") || val.equals(".")) flag = 1;
                if (choice_spinner.equals("Temperature")) {
                    if (flag == 0) {
                        double celcius = Double.parseDouble(val);
                        if (from_spinner_position == 2) {
                            celcius = celcius - Double.parseDouble("32");
                            celcius = celcius * Double.parseDouble("0.55555");
                        } else if (from_spinner_position == 1)
                            celcius = celcius - Double.parseDouble("273.15");

                        if (to_spinner_position == 2) {
                            celcius = celcius * Double.parseDouble("1.8");
                            celcius = celcius + Double.parseDouble("32");
                        } else if (to_spinner_position == 1)
                            celcius = celcius + Double.parseDouble("273.15");
                        print_exponent(result, celcius);
                    } else {
                        result.setText("");
                    }

                } else {
                    if (flag == 0) {
                        double temp = Double.parseDouble(val);
                        temp = temp / Double.parseDouble(array[choice_spinner_pos][from_spinner_position].toString());
                        temp = temp * Double.parseDouble(array[choice_spinner_pos][to_spinner_position].toString());
                        temp = temp / Double.parseDouble(array[choice_spinner_pos][0].toString());
                        print_exponent(result, temp);
                    } else {
                        result.setText("");
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    //Method to print the numbers in exponent form
    public void print_exponent(TextView view, double temp) {
        String temp1 = "" + temp;
        String temp2 = "";
        int bds = 0;
        for (char c : temp1.toCharArray()) {
            if (c == 'E') {
                temp2 += " e ";
                bds = 1;
            } else {
                if (bds == 1) {
                    if (c == '-')
                        temp2 += c;
                    else
                        temp2 = temp2 + "+" + c;
                } else
                    temp2 += c;
                bds = 0;
            }
        }
        view.setText(temp2);
    }

    //This method takes a big decimal number and convert that to the exponent from and scale is mantissa
    private static String format(BigDecimal x, int scale) {
        NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.0E0");
        formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(scale);
        return formatter.format(x);
    }


    //Spinner class to select spinner and also add gender
    class spinner implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (parent.getId() == R.id.conversion_type) {

                quantity.getText().clear();
                result.setText("");
                choice_spinner = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                choice_spinner_pos = position;
                from_spinner.setEnabled(true);
                to_spinner.setEnabled(true);
                if (choice_spinner.equals("Area") == true) {
                    adapter_area.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    from_spinner.setAdapter(adapter_area);
                    to_spinner.setAdapter(adapter_area);
                } else if (choice_spinner.equals("Length") == true) {
                    adapter_length.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    from_spinner.setAdapter(adapter_length);
                    to_spinner.setAdapter(adapter_length);
                } else if (choice_spinner.equals("Temperature") == true) {
                    adapter_temperature.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    from_spinner.setAdapter(adapter_temperature);
                    to_spinner.setAdapter(adapter_temperature);
                } else if (parent.getId() == R.id.from_spinner) {
                    quantity.getText().clear();
                    result.setText("");
                    from_spinner_string = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    from_spinner_position = position;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Select a category", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            from_spinner.setEnabled(false);
            to_spinner.setEnabled(false);
        }

        public void clear_unit (View view){
            quantity.setText("");
            result.setText("");
            val = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Root cause**

In the `MainActivity`, the `unit_converter()` method is responsible for initializing `Spinner`, set adapters, set listeners for the `Spinner`, but you forgot to call this method when the activity is starting.

**Solution**

Call the `unit_converter()` method when the activity is starting.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    unit_converter();
}
```

**Update**

When users select `from_spinner` and `to_spinner`, you do not update `from_spinner_position` and `to_spinner_position`  value. Change your code to:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (parent.getId() == R.id.conversion_type) {
        quantity.getText().clear();
        result.setText("");
        choice_spinner = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        choice_spinner_pos = position;
        from_spinner.setEnabled(true);
        to_spinner.setEnabled(true);
        if (choice_spinner.equals("Area") == true) {
            adapter_area.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            from_spinner.setAdapter(adapter_area);
            to_spinner.setAdapter(adapter_area);
        } else if (choice_spinner.equals("Length") == true) {
            adapter_length.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            from_spinner.setAdapter(adapter_length);
            to_spinner.setAdapter(adapter_length);
        } else if (choice_spinner.equals("Temperature") == true) {
            adapter_temperature.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            from_spinner.setAdapter(adapter_temperature);
            to_spinner.setAdapter(adapter_temperature);
        } else if (parent.getId() == R.id.from_spinner) {
            quantity.getText().clear();
            result.setText("");
            from_spinner_string = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            from_spinner_position = position;
        }
    } else if (parent.getId() == R.id.from_spinner) {
        from_spinner_position = position;
    } else if (parent.getId() == R.id.to_spinner) {
        to_spinner_position = position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! It worked!!! But i need your help again... Its working now but if i enter a number value the the result is still the number value... It doesn't convert it.. i entered a number to convert it from celsius to kelvin but it still prints out that same number... Not conversion.. can you help please?

Comment: @Fedan Let me take a look the source code again and let you know where the problem is.

Comment: Okay  I'm waiting... I'd be grateful if you help me out please 

Comment: @Fedan See my updated answer. I just add 2 `else-if` statement at the end.

Comment: Woaaw!!! You're the best man!! It worked!!!!  You're the best!!!!!! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I'm a bit new at this... I started a month ago... How can i comtact you? In case I'm in need of help

Comment: @Fedan If you have any questions then you can post them on Stackoverflow, so many people will help you out. By the way, as a beginner, you should take some videos, tutorials to learn the basics of Android programming (you will find them on Youtube, blogspot, android developer site, etc.). It will help you develop Android apps faster and better.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, then you can mark it as answer or vote up. It will help me improving my answers in the future. Happy coding :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226037/discussion-between-son-truong-and-fedan).